# Problems with Tomcat 7 and SSL config

Tags: web-services, security, tomcat, ssl, https

I am trying to configure SSL with Tomcat 7 in eclipse for java.I have configured server.xml :

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="/.keystore" keystorePass="mypass" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I am doing a application client/server, the server works good but when I execute the client I have the following error:

> > Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: jav
> >     ax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> >     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKI X path building failed:
> >     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExcepti on: unable to
> >     find valid certification path to requested target
> >             at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle
> >     (URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
> >             at clientWAN.client.main(client.java:109) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.Validator
> >     Exception: PKIX path building failed:
> >     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPath BuilderException: unable to
> >     find valid certification path to requested target
> >             at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source
> >     )
> >             at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
> >     (Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown S
> >     ource)
> >             at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unk
> >     nown Source)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.ge
> >     tOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:238)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(Committ
> >     ingOutputStream.java:117)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutp
> >     utStream.java:89)
> >             at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.ja
> >     va:191)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writ
> >     eToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.BaseFormProvider.writeTo(Bas
> >     eFormProvider.java:109)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider.writeTo(FormPro
> >     vider.java:88)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider.writeTo(FormPro
> >     vider.java:58)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWri
> >     ter.java:300)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invok
> >     e(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
> >             at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle
> >     (URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
> >             ... 5 more Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
> >     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> >     find vali d certification path to requested target
> >             at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Sour
> >     ce)
> >             ... 35 more Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to 
> >     find valid certification path to requested target
> >             at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Sourc
> >     e)
> >             at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown 
> >     Source)
> >             at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
> >             ... 41 more

I don't know the cause for this problem.I have seen several similar problems in this web, but I have been unable to solve. I need to help.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your client doesn't trust the server certificate. Get it signed, or export it into the client's truststore.